# Filter posts by month (dropdown)

Tags: posts, filters, dropdown

Good day! I am building this Blog Archive page and it requires filtering of posts by months, using dropdown. Any idea how to do this?

[image]

```
<?php
       // what goes here

      printf('<option value=".%s">%s</option>', `what_here`, `what_here`);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [wp_get_archives()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/) function. 
Example from this link:

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value=""><?php esc_attr( _e( 'Select Month', 'textdomain' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make use of this. Another question though, when you want to load the blogs on the same page, it requires AJAX, correct? Currently the code given above directs to a new page.